# downloading a reference genome for alignment

Tags: bioinformatics

I am currently working through the code example on the [MATLAB website.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/exploring-protein-dna-binding-sites-from-paired-end-chip-seq-data.html?prodcode=BI&language=en) It requires me to download the reference genome of [Arabidopsis thaliana (thale cress)](http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_organism?org=ath) so I can use BowTie2 to align the Chip-Seq experiment data. I need it in a .fa file.

Since I am very very new to this, what is the database where I can use to download this reference genome? How do I search for something like this? Thanks

EDIT: spoke too soon. I think the [NCBI website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=thale%20cress) did it for me. Under the `Representitive -> Reference genome` section. Is this correct?

EDIT2: The answer was in the MATLAB page also. The bioinformatics toolbox provides a function:

```
% getgenbank('NC_003070','FileFormat','fasta','tofile','ach1.fasta');
% getgenbank('NC_003071','FileFormat','fasta','tofile','ach2.fasta');
% getgenbank('NC_003074','FileFormat','fasta','tofile','ach3.fasta');
% getgenbank('NC_003075','FileFormat','fasta','tofile','ach4.fasta');
% getgenbank('NC_003076','FileFormat','fasta','tofile','ach5.fasta');
```

Comment: Yes, NCBI is fine. So is http://genome.ucsc.edu or http://ensembl.org or [genomes online](http://genomesonline.org/cgi-bin/GOLD/index.cgigenomes.org).

Comment: Some organisms have special repositories like Drosophila has flybase.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bowtie, you want the indexed genome, see if that's not available here, instead of downloading the fasta and indexing it yourself.

http://support.illumina.com/sequencing/sequencing_software/igenome.ilmn